# "exec env -" wrong path when installing bazel

Tags: linux, shell, bazel

when I compile bazel 0.5.4 from source

./compile.sh meet this problem :

```
error executing shell command: 'cp 'bazel-out/local-opt/bin/src/main/protobuf/command_server_java_grpc_srcs.jar' 'bazel-out/local-opt/bin/src/main/protobuf/command_server_java_grpc_srcs.srcjar'' failed (Exit 127): bash failed: error executing command
  (cd /tmp/bazel_b29JWvqF/out/execroot/io_bazel && \
  exec env - \
  /bin/bash -c 'cp '\''bazel-out/local-opt/bin/src/main/protobuf/command_server_java_grpc_srcs.jar'\'' '\''bazel-out/local-opt/bin/src/main/protobuf/command_server_java_grpc_srcs.srcjar'\''').
/bin/bash: cp: command not found
Target //src:bazel failed to build
```

I think it's because the "exec env - " use wrong $PATH environment.

when I only run "exec env - " command :

```
$ exec env - /bin/bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

but the cp command is under /bin/cp

and I confirm "/bin" is in system's $PATH variable.

which configuration should I modify?

Comment: `/usr/bin/cp` probably exists as a symlink to `/bin/cp` or vice versa.

Comment: The quoting around the file name looks wacky, too.

Comment: The error message seems to come from deep inside the Bazel logic itself. I don't think there is anything you could straightforwardly fix. Raise two bug reports, one about this issue, and one about the many silly errors in their shell scripts (try http://shellcheck.net/ for diagnostics). The top-level [`compile.sh`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/compile.sh) looks acceptable but there are many oddities when you delve into their scripts (simple quoting errors, odd [`echo` in backticks](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) etc).

Answer (score 0):

You need indeed to change your `$PATH`, in your shell type after the prompt

```
export PATH=/bin:$PATH;
```

however since `cp` is a fundamental command I would recommend to modify your `$PATH` in your `.bash_profile` / `.profile` in your `$HOME` to keep the changes after you reboot your machine or run another shell

Last but not least, you can add `-i` option to your `exec env` call and define a list of env variable to use:

```
exec env -i PATH=$PATH HOME=$HOME TERM=$TERM PS1='\u:\w\$ ' /bin/bash
```

Comment: “exec env -  " can not inherit  $PATH virable.

Comment: see my edit with the `-i` option! I hope this helps you

Comment: The entries in `PATH` are directories which contain binaries, not the individual names of the binaries.

Comment: @tripleee: ooppss sorry typo, edited now! and of course that PATH should point to the directories containing the binaries. Nicely picked up

Comment: hi , which PATH environment does "exec env - " use ? I count not add extra "-i" param, is there a config file I can modify ?